# Change UISearchBar options highlighted color ios 7

Tags: uisearchbar, searchbar

i'm developing an app for ios 7 and i want to change the close button highlighted blue color to purple so all be the same

here is the image it will describe what i want to do

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/199/pg9l.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Appearance API to alter the tint color of UIBarButtonItems contained in the search bar:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```